# How to repeat same keyword for an array of test data in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I want to execute the same keyword for an array of input in robot framework. 
For ex:

```
*** Test Case ***
Login to gmail  ${UserIDs}  ${passwords}
```

Here, UserIDs and Passwords are an array and I wish to execute the keyword 'Login to gmail' for all the input in those arrays. I know that the keyword mentioned here wont work. But, I am looking help to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Using a :FOR loop

If your constraint is that the usernames and passwords must be stored in arrays, and you all this in a single test case, your only solution is to use a loop. In this case, since you want to iterate over two equal-length arrays you can use the `IN ZIP` variant of robot's looping mechanism. In order for all iterations to run even if one failed, you can use [run keyword and continue on failure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure) within the loop.

Example:

```
*** Variables ***
@{userIDs}    one@example.com  two@example.com  badguy@example.com
@{passwords}  secretpassword   secretPassword  SecretPassword

*** Keywords ***
Login to gmail
    [Arguments]  ${userID}  ${password}
    should not be true  $userID == "badguy@example.com"  
    ...  cannot login as bad guy

*** Test case***
Example
    :FOR  ${userID}  ${password}  IN ZIP  ${userIDs}  ${passwords}
    \  run keyword and continue on failure
    \  ...  login to gmail  ${userID}  ${password}
```

### Using a template

A more common solution is to use a test template. This allows you to specify keyword to be run for each test, and then the test itself contains the data (ie: the data is not stored in arrays).

Example:

```
*** Keywords ***
Login to gmail
    [Arguments]  ${userID}  ${password}
    should not be true  $userID == "badguy@example.com"  
    ...  cannot login as bad guy

*** Test case***
Gmail logins
    [Template]  login to gmail
    # username          # password
    one@example.com     secretpassword
    two@example.com     bogus
    badguy@example.com  letmein
```

### Using a test template for the suite

A third solution is to use one template for the whole suite. One advantage to this is that each success or failure is recorded as a separate test, and can have a unique name.

Example:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template  Login to gmail

*** Keywords ***
Login to gmail
    [Arguments]  ${userID}  ${password}
    should not be true  $userID == "badguy@example.com"  
    ...  cannot login as bad guy

*** Test case***
# test case name                  # username          # password
valid username/password           one@example.com     secretpassword
valid username, invalid password  two@example.com     bogus
invalid username                  badguy@example.com  letmein
```